# Jetpack Compose SwipeToDelete does not work properly

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

Hi I have an app with Jetpack Compose that has a list and user can add or delete items in that list. That list  also recording to the FireBaseFireStore. Updating added items synchronously is successful but when i try to delete an item from list, LazyColumn's behaviour is being weird. İt deletes all items sometimes or delete selected item and under of it. I guess that's because i'm using list.clear() method in my retriever function but if I don't use `clear()` method then it duplicates items when i try to add another item. So how can i solve that problem ? If i use arrayList instead of MutableStateList then deleting operation being succesful but then lazyColumn does not update itself when adding the new item. I'm in a paradox pls help me.

Here is my code snippets :

***DataRetriever Function:***

```
override suspend fun getAnalysisListFromFirebase(
        analyzeList: MutableList<AnalyzeModel>,
        currentPairId: String
    ) {
        pairCollection
            .document(currentPairId)
            .collection("Analysis").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->

                try {
                    if (value != null && !value.isEmpty) {

                        val documents = value.documents

                        analyzeList.clear()

                        documents.forEach {

                            val analyze = it.toObject(AnalyzeModel::class.java)

                            if (analyze != null) {

                                analyzeList.add(analyze)
                            }
                        }


                    } else if (error != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(Application(), error.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show()
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
    }
```

***Delete From Firebase Function :***

```
override suspend fun deleteFromFirebase(analyzeId: String,pairId: String, context: Context) {

        try {
            pairCollection.document(pairId).collection("Analysis").document(analyzeId).delete().await()
        }catch (e: Exception) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {

                Toast.makeText(context, e.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
      }
}
```

***Lazy Column Composable :***

```
Surface(modifier = Modifier
                 .fillMaxSize()
                 .padding(it)
                ) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {
                        HeaderText(header = pairName, modifier = Modifier)

                        LazyColumn() {
                            items(analyzeList) { analyze ->



                                val swipeToDeleteState = rememberDismissState(
                                    confirmStateChange = {
                                        if (it == DismissValue.DismissedToStart) {
                                            scope.launch {
                                                viewModel.deleteFromFirebase(analyze.id,currencyId)
                                                analyzeList.remove(analyze)
                                            }
                                        }
                                        true
                                    }
                                )

                                SwipeToDismiss(
                                    state = swipeToDeleteState,
                                    background = {
                                        val color = when (swipeToDeleteState.dismissDirection) {
                                            DismissDirection.EndToStart -> Color.Red
                                            DismissDirection.StartToEnd -> Color.Transparent
                                            null -> Color.Transparent
                                        }
                                        Box(
                                            modifier = Modifier
                                                .fillParentMaxSize()
                                                .background(color = color)
                                                .padding(8.dp)
                                        ) {
                                            Icon(
                                                imageVector = Icons.Default.Delete,
                                                contentDescription = "Delete",
                                                tint = Color.White,
                                                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd)
                                            )
                                        }
                                    },
                                    dismissContent = {
                                        AnalyzeRow(analyze = analyze)
                                    },
                                    directions=setOf(DismissDirection.EndToStart)
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Thanks in advance.